# Too many ajax calls when form selections change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My webpage has two main sections: (1) search criteria (selection boxes in a form) used to access database information, and (2) a div in which the results are displayed. When the page loads initially, default values in the form are serialized and sent via ajax to php and the results are rendered. This results section is paginated to display all the results by clicking next, previous, etc. This all works perfectly.

Here’s the problem: each time the user makes a change to the criteria and the form’s data is serialized and sent via ajax, another layer of results is added somehow. When paginating through the results, it processes page 2 for each of the “layers” but only the last one that arrives from the server is displayed on the webpage. So, every time another change is made, another layer is added. Since ajax is asynchronous, the results displayed may or may not be the correct “layer.”

HTML:

```
<form id='submitCriteria' action='' method='post'>
    <select id='selLevel' class='selectpicker'  name='levels'>
        <option title='Levels' value='No Preference' 
            selected = 'selected'>No Preference</option>
        <option title='Levels:<br>  1+' value=1 >1+ </option>
        <option title='Levels:<br>  2+' value=2 >2+ </option>
        <option title='Levels:<br>  3+' value=3 >3+ </option>
    </select>
</form>

<!-- Pagination: -->
<div id="spinnerDet" class="spinnerA">
</div>
<div id="paginationdiv"> 
    <div id="pagination_container">
        <div class="pagination">
            <ul><li class="inactive">Previous</li>
                <li class="pagerange">
                    <span class="total" a=" 58">
                        Page 1 of 58 </span></li>
                <li p="2" class="active">Next</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- Output from server: -->
        <table>
            <tr><td>Levels</td><td>3</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript/jQuery:

```
$("#submitCriteria").change(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $.ajax({
         type: 'post',
         data: $("#submitCriteria").serialize(),
         url: "/load_plans.php",
         success: function(data) {
             paginateDetails (data)
         },
    });
    return false;
});

function paginateDetails (data) {
   selDetails = JSON.parse(data); 
   var levels = selDetails.levels;
   var totalsline = "Number of levels: " + levels;
   $('#numResults').removeClass('spinnerA');
   $('#numResults').addClass('stop-spin'); 
   $('#numResults').html(totalsline);  
   loadData(1); //initial output based on default values

   // Pagination buttons event:
   $('#paginationdiv').on('click touchend', 
   '#pagination_container .pagination li.active', function (e) {
       e.stopPropagation(); 
       e.preventDefault(); 
       var page = $(this).attr('p');
       loadData(page);
   });

   function loadData(page) { 
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           data: eval("'page=' + page + '&levels=' + levels"),
           url: "loadDetails.php",
           success: function (msg) {
               $("#pagination_container").ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
                   $("#pagination_container").html(msg);
               });
           }
       });
   }
}
```

How do I eliminate another “layer” when selections in the form are changed/updated?

Comment: Please post your full code including HTML of your results "layer" and contents of paginateDetails() function

Comment: Added the HTML results and the paginateDetails() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the structure of your code, in this case you shouldn't be nesting the functions. Also you are repeatedly attaching click event to #paginationdiv (does it get removed and reatached when you reload data? You should use class instead of div in that case).

Without trying the code, i believe your problem might be caused by your loadData function - in your success callback you don't need to hook ajax complete again, success is called when your request is complete and successfull. I believe that part of your code was triggering twice ( on success and when ajaxComplete fired)

Your refactored code should look something like this:

```
$("#submitCriteria").change(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: $("#submitCriteria").serialize(),
        url: "/load_plans.php",
        success: function(data) {
            paginateDetails (data)
        },
    });
    return false;
});

function loadData(page) { 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: eval("'page=' + page + '&levels=' + levels"),
        url: "loadDetails.php",
        success: function (msg) {
            //$("#pagination_container").ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
                $("#pagination_container").html(msg);
            //});
        }
    });
}

function paginateDetails (data) {
    selDetails = JSON.parse(data); 
    var levels = selDetails.levels;
    var totalsline = "Number of levels: " + levels;
    $('#numResults').removeClass('spinnerA');
    $('#numResults').addClass('stop-spin'); 
    $('#numResults').html(totalsline);  
    loadData(1); //initial output based on default values

    // remove previous click handlers
    $('#paginationdiv').off()
    // Pagination buttons event:
    $('#paginationdiv').on('click touchend', 
    '#pagination_container .pagination li.active', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var page = $(this).attr('p');
        loadData(page);
    });
}
```

Comment: $('#paginationdiv').off() is what fixed it. Turns out the ajaxComplete was not needed, and I removed it. Thank you very, very much!